# Flutter - why is my text is disappearing if i added to much text against its length

Tags: flutter, uitextfield, flutter-layout, flutter-text

As said in the title; my text "disappears" when I added text too much against the length of the textfield, why does this happens??

Here's the code

```
Container(
                                 height: mediaSize.height * .075,
                                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                     borderRadius:
                                         BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.5)),
                                     boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                       BoxShadow(
                                           color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.45),
                                           spreadRadius: 1,
                                           blurRadius: 4,
                                           offset: Offset(3.5, 4))
                                     ]),
                                 child: TextFormField(
                                   decoration: InputDecoration(
                                       focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                           borderSide:
                                               BorderSide(color: myLightOrangeColor),
                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                               Radius.circular(12.5))),
                                       enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                           borderSide: BorderSide(
                                               color: myLightOrangeColor, width: 6),
                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                               Radius.circular(12.5))),
       
                                       labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                       filled: true,
                                       fillColor: Colors.white),
                                   keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                 ),
                               ),
```

When I add to much of text this happens: [first one ok] [next one ???]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add some more code the parent widgets, Maybe this is because of some height that is bonding it to a cut.

Comment: The problem is the size that you're adding to the container, remove that height and the behavior of the text field will return to normal.

Comment: Hi @LOfG, I found your solution working very well. But, I have to resize its height. Do you have any solutions for this without damaging the function of the text. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Hi, so to help you, i need to know what is the final result that you want to achieve and why do you need to change the height of this Container.

Comment: @LOfG, Im currently bummed out how normal height of textfield looks, it does not go well with my style or the ui layout design so I modified its height. The normal height given is just bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the text of the TextField to appear normally it needs his normal height, in the image below an image without giving height to the Container:

[image]

But if you give it less height than it need to show the text this happen (in the example the height of the device multiplied by 0.075):

[image]

To reduce the height of the TextField you can change the property `contentPadding` or set the `isDense` to `true`:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    isDense: true,
    //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0), //or any padding you want
      ),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  ),
),
```

Comment: I see it has like a content padding thats why smaller the height, the higher to see less text. Is there a possible way to lower the height without damaging the content padding :/ ??

Comment: You can change the internal padding of the TextField, i have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @LofG, The isdense didnt worked for me, but the content padding worked perfectly. Thanks for the help it was a big progress for me had this problem for a while. I tagged your answer as most helpful. THANKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS

Comment: Glad i can help!